# How do you split microsoft teams participant cameras and shared screen to separate monitors?

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can I put the cameras of meeting participants on one monitor and have the meeting organizer's shared screen on another monitor (in a multi-monitor client setup). This would allow shared screens to be maximized at the same time as maximizing the size of participant cameras.

Comment: We are mainly responsible for Microsoft Teams app development related issues. For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is not possible at the moment.  If anyone would like this feature, please vote for this suggestion or one like it https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/058a22d1-aa73-ec11-a81b-6045bd7bf64c